Postgres function taking 10 minutes for 8 million rows
I have 8 million rows of data from combining these four tables (tbl_user, tbl_missing_child_detail, tbl_recovery_child_detail, tbl_child_profile_details).
The function is working fine but it's taking up to 10 minutes. I'm using this function to count specific rows
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.status_of_data_entry_by_different_stack_holders(
    ldg_code integer,
    report_type integer,
    created_at_from timestamp without time zone,
    created_at_to timestamp without time zone
)
    RETURNS TABLE(lgd_code integer, state_district_name character varying, total_ps bigint) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    -- Declare variables to store the dynamic SQL and table name
    order_by_condition text;
    sql_query text;
    table_name text;
    select_column_name text;
    join_condition text;
    join_cases text;
    single_cases text;
BEGIN
    -- Determine the order by condition based on the report_type
    order_by_condition := CASE 
        WHEN report_type = 1 THEN 'd.state_name'
        WHEN report_type IN (2, 3) THEN 'd.name'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    -- Determine the table name based on the report_type
    table_name := CASE 
        WHEN report_type = 1 THEN 'tbl_master_state'
        WHEN report_type IN (2, 3) THEN 'tbl_master_police_districts'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    -- Determine the SELECT column names based on the report_type
    select_column_name := CASE 
        WHEN report_type = 1 THEN 'd.state_lgd_code, d.state_name'
        WHEN report_type IN (2, 3) THEN 'd.id, d.name'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    -- Determine the joining table names based on the report_type
    join_condition := CASE 
        WHEN report_type IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 
            'LEFT JOIN tbl_missing_child_detail AS m ON m.user_id = b.id AND m.miss_date BETWEEN $1 AND $2
             LEFT JOIN tbl_recovery_child_detail AS r ON r.user_id = b.id AND r.rec_date BETWEEN $1 AND $2
             LEFT JOIN tbl_child_profile_details AS c ON c.user_id = b.id AND c.case_ref_date BETWEEN $1 AND $2'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    join_cases := CASE
        WHEN report_type = 1 THEN 'JOIN tbl_user AS b ON b.state = d.state_lgd_code AND b.police_district_id IS NOT NULL'
        WHEN report_type = 2 THEN 'JOIN tbl_user AS b ON b.state = d.state AND (b.police_district_id = d.id OR b.police_district_id IS NOT NULL)'
        WHEN report_type = 3 THEN 'JOIN tbl_user AS b ON b.police_district_id = d.id'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    single_cases := CASE
        WHEN report_type = 1 THEN 'd.state_lgd_code'
        WHEN report_type = 2 THEN 'd.state'
        WHEN report_type = 3 THEN 'd.id'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    -- Build the dynamic SQL
    sql_query := 
    FORMAT(
        'SELECT %s,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN b.user_role = 33 THEN 1 END) AS total_ps
        FROM %I d
        %s %s
        WHERE
            (CASE
                WHEN %s = 1 THEN true
                WHEN %s = 2 THEN %s = %s
                WHEN %s = 3 THEN %s = %s
                ELSE true
            END)
        GROUP BY %s 
        ORDER BY %s',
        select_column_name, table_name, join_cases, join_condition, 
        report_type, report_type, single_cases, ldg_code, 
        report_type, single_cases, ldg_code, 
        select_column_name, order_by_condition
    );

    -- Print debugging messages
    RAISE NOTICE 'SQL Query: %', sql_query;

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql_query USING created_at_from, created_at_to;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT 0::integer, 'Not Available'::character varying, 0::BIGINT;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION common.status_of_data_entry_by_different_stack_holders(
  integer, integer, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone)
  OWNER TO postgres;

I also added an index on columns that I used:
Sort (cost=191695.37..191695.46 rows=36 width=330) (actual time=225611.966..225611.973 rows=36 loops=1)
 Output: d.state_lgd_code, d.state_name, (count(CASE WHEN (b.user_role = 33) THEN 1 ELSE NULL::integer END))
 Sort Key: d.state_name
 Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 27kB
 Buffers: shared hit=123378 dirtied=4

When I was trying to use another join it was not returning any data.
Are there some other ways I could try to speed it up?

Please add sample/mock data and DDL for tables it's supposed to work with (MRE), to allow others to test this function. MySQL is a different RDBMS, not just a sql that is yours. Based on the language plpgsql and overall syntax, I'm assuming out of the two tags you used, it's PostgreSQL you're really on.

Please review [mre] and update the post with table DDL (including indexes), example data, expected output, the generated query, and the results of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) when running that query. It would also be helpful to have each table's row count instead of just the combined row count.

Thanks for you response, actually i was just using postgres function to count data only from given tables i have also maked index that i was using columns
"Sort  (cost=191695.37..191695.46 rows=36 width=330) (actual time=225611.966..225611.973 rows=36 loops=1)"
"  Output: d.state_lgd_code, d.state_name, (count(CASE WHEN (b.user_role = 33) THEN 1 ELSE NULL::integer END))"
"  Sort Key: d.state_name"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=123378 dirtied=4"
in this i'm not able to attached image. using given function i wanted to count data

@HariomVishwakarma Please only add requested updates by editing the question. It's still missing the DDL (Data Definition Language, basically CREATE statements) for tables and indexes this function is supposed to work on, sample data (INSERTs of some mock rows). If you want to paste an explain of an example invocation of the query this function ends up assembling, paste it in full.

in comment section it was taking only 500 characters how can i send DDL?

@HariomVishwakarma There's an edit button right under your post. Add things into the body of the question, then clean up the comments. Leaving lengthy comment sections tends to discourage visitors.

Try to identify which of the statements in the function takes that long. Then ask a question about that statement and provide EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output for it. Then we can help you analyze the problem.

I'd really reconsider whether this much dynamic SQL construction is really clearer, faster, more convenient to use and maintainable than simply preparing 3 parametrised statements for the 3 report types, or letting this function switch between 3 fully assembled and readable statements.
That would at least follow KISS, while in its current form, this really follows neither KISS, nor DRY. On top of that, fully assembled statements can benefit from query plan caching.
It's unlikely the changes proposed below will get you anywhere near what a very simple index setup tweak could. Unless you post how big and distinct those tables are and what your current index setup is, that's a major blind spot.

The two last conditions in your WHERE(CASE were identical. This was likely reduced by the query rewriter/planner/optimiser, but it could be a sign you misaligned or otherwise confused your placeholders or variables, intending to do something else.
The whole WHERE section can be reduced to report_type NOT IN (2,3) OR single_cases = ldg_code
This is likely not what you want
AND (b.police_district_id = d.id OR b.police_district_id IS NOT NULL)

Unless it's a convoluted null-check of d.id, it reduces to this:
AND b.police_district_id IS NOT NULL

You might actually be trying to simply
AND d.id IS NOT NULL 
AND b.police_district_id IS NOT NULL

Which is a bit clearer, while serving the same purpose.
This:
COUNT(CASE WHEN b.user_role = 33 THEN 1 END)

will attempt to process all rows. You can instead use an aggregate filter clause:
COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE b.user_role=33)

It's faster and only processes the rows you actually wish to count.
You might also consider moving that down to regular WHERE section and adding the assumption that all missing state_lgd_code, state_name in report type 1 or id, name in report type 2 and 3, indicate a count of 0. It might even be faster to join that to distinct groups afterwards and coalesce() those to 0.

sql_query :=FORMAT($dsql$ SELECT %1$s --select_column_name
                               , COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE b.user_role = 33) AS total_ps
                          FROM %2$I --table_name
                                    AS d 
                          %3$s --join_cases
                          %4$s --join_condition
                          WHERE $3 --report_type
                                   NOT IN (2,3)
                             OR %5$s --single_cases
                                     = $4 --ldg_code
                          GROUP BY %1$s --select_column_name
                          ORDER BY %6$s --order_by_condition
                   $dsql$
                   , select_column_name, table_name, join_cases, join_condition
                   , single_cases, order_by_condition );
RAISE NOTICE 'SQL Query: %', sql_query;-- Print debugging messages
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql_query USING created_at_from, created_at_to, report_type, ldg_code;-- Execute the dynamic SQL


If you number your format() placeholders (%1$s instead of just %s), you don't need to repeat the variables you're replacing them with. It also makes it easier to follow, spot repetitions as well as accidental swaps resulting from misalignment.
Instead of being formatted into it as literals, the report_type and ldg_code can be passed into the query as parameters with USING as $3 and $4, the same way you're supplying created_at_from and created_at_to as $1 and $2.
Some IDEs will be able to use syntax highlighting inside your dynamic SQL, if you wrap those dynamic statements in named dollar quotes $dsql$, instead of singles '.

